# Pass data between express router and middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to write express middleware to check the validity of a JWT in the Authorization header. This seems quite easy but I don't want it to run on all routes (e.g. not on login/signup routers).

So, I'd like to specify in the router declaration that a route should require a valid token. E.g. something like this

```
const controllers = require('../controllers');

module.exports = (app) => {

    app.post('/auth/signup', controllers.auth.signup.post);
    app.post('/auth/login', controllers.auth.login.post);

    app.get('/teams', controllers.teams.get, {requiresToken:true});

};
```

Except, .post and .get don't take a third parameter and the controller only takes (req,res,next) parameters so I can't really see a way of passing startic data for each route. I'm sure I'm missing something simple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how i created a middleware to pass the data into

```
module.exports = function(options) {
   return function (req, res, next) {
        //write your code here
        // here you can access options variable
        console.log(options.data)
        next();
   }
}
```

How you call that middleware is like this

```
app.use(middleware({'data' : 'Test'}));
```

To use on route basis

```
app.post('/userRegistration', middleware({'data' : 'Test'}), (req, res) => {});
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, that allows you to pass data in to the middleware, once, when instantiating the middleware. Not, per route when instantiating the route?

Comment: Hi @jonhobbs, i updated the answer to add `route basis middleware`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not entirely understanding how the middleware is called explicitly inside a call to an "auth" function in the middle, but your answer has shown me that multiple functions can be chained together for each route so I could just call an auth function for each route and not use middleware at all by the looks of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude the `auth` subroute from this middleware using negative lookup regexp:

```
const controllers = require('../controllers');

module.exports = (app) => {

    app.use(/\/((?!auth).)*/, yourJwtTokenValidatorMethod); // replace with your jwt token validator middleware

    app.post('/auth/signup', controllers.auth.signup.post);
    app.post('/auth/login', controllers.auth.login.post);

    app.get('/teams', controllers.teams.get, {requiresToken:true});

};
```